# Unable to get Selenium webdriver to stop closing safari browser

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari

Having issues getting safari to not close the browser upon completion of the code below. Chrome and Firefox stay up, but safari closes the second it finishes. I am using Webdriver, and writing with javascript.

````
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("safari").build();
    await driver.get("http://website.com");
    await driver.findElement(By.name("os_username")).sendKeys("username");
    await driver.findElement(By.name("os_password")).sendKeys("password");
    await driver.findElement(By.name("login")).sendKeys(Key.RETURN);

    // input search bar data, and click return.
    await driver.sleep(5000);
    await driver.findElement(By.name("searchString")).sendKeys("Name");
    await driver.findElement(By.name("searchString")).sendKeys(Key.RETURN);
    await driver.sleep(10000);
}
safariLogin(); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can just prevent the script from ending using a breakpoint at the end.

Comment: I've tried several inline breakpoints to no avail. have also attempted setTimeout, or adding debugger. All still close the safari window at end of execution.

Comment: So it seems like it fails to get to the end of the execution, You can edit the post and add the code.

Comment: No, it completes and then closes, it happens very quickly besides the login data. the code above is all the code i have for it for right now, besides adding the selenium web driver at the top. The code is the same mostly for the 4 browsers i am attempting to test, but safari is the only one showing this behavior. i added no close() or quits() because i am looking to continue adding to this code as part of my testing suite.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I think there is no reference for Key.RETURN in safari, try using sendKeys("\n")